# Create table in Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ddl

I have created the table "Risiko" which shouldntbe dynamic, i tought it would be that simple but it was not. How should i solve it? and what am i doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLERISIKO IS


    BEGIN
       drop table risiko;
       CREATE TABLE Risiko
          (
          RNr       INTEGER,
          Projekt       INTEGER,
          Text       VARCHAR(25),
          Gruppe       INTEGER,
          Auswirkung    INTEGER,
          WKeit       INTEGER,
          Pruefdatum    DATE,
          PRIMARY KEY    (RNr),
          CONSTRAINT FKRisiko1 FOREIGN KEY (Projekt)
          REFERENCES Projekt(ProNr),
          CONSTRAINT FKRisiko2 FOREIGN KEY (Gruppe)
          REFERENCES Risikogruppe (RGNr),
          CONSTRAINT PosAuswirkung CHECK(Auswirkung >=0),
          CONSTRAINT WKeitProzent CHECK(WKeit>=0 AND WKeit<=100)
          );

       INSERT INTO Risiko 
       VALUES(1,1,'Anforderungenunklar',1,50000,30
       ,TO_DATE('25.01.06','DD.MM.YY'));
       INSERT INTO Risiko 
       VALUES(2,1,'Abnahmeprozess offen',2,30000,70
       ,TO_DATE('26.02.06','DD.MM.YY'));
       INSERT INTO Risiko
       VALUES(3,2,'Ansprechpartner wechseln',1,20000,80
       ,TO_DATE('06.05.06','DD.MM.YY'));
       INSERT INTO Risiko
       VALUES(4,2,'neue Entwicklungsumgebung',3,40000,20
       ,TO_DATE('05.10.06','DD.MM.YY'));

    END;
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: You should avoid two-digit years. `date '2006-10-05'` is the simplest and most reliable way to write a date literal.

Comment: Very, very bad idea creating tables in procedure unless for training purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we can't write DDL statements directly in PL/SQL block, for example when we write

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLERISIKO IS
BEGIN
    drop table risiko;
    CREATE TABLE Risiko
    (
        RNr       INTEGER,
        Projekt       INTEGER,
        Text       VARCHAR(25),
        Gruppe       INTEGER,
        Auswirkung    INTEGER,
        WKeit       INTEGER,
        Pruefdatum    DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY    (RNr),
        CONSTRAINT FKRisiko1 FOREIGN KEY (Projekt)
        REFERENCES Projekt(ProNr),
        CONSTRAINT FKRisiko2 FOREIGN KEY (Gruppe)
        REFERENCES Risikogruppe (RGNr),
        CONSTRAINT PosAuswirkung CHECK(Auswirkung >=0),
        CONSTRAINT WKeitProzent CHECK(WKeit>=0 AND WKeit<=100)
    );
    INSERT INTO Risiko VALUES(1,1,'Anforderungenunklar',1,50000,30 ,TO_DATE('25.01.06','DD.MM.YY'));
    INSERT INTO Risiko VALUES(2,1,'Abnahmeprozess offen',2,30000,70 ,TO_DATE('26.02.06','DD.MM.YY'));
    INSERT INTO Risiko VALUES(3,2,'Ansprechpartner wechseln',1,20000,80 ,TO_DATE('06.05.06','DD.MM.YY'));
    INSERT INTO Risiko VALUES(4,2,'neue Entwicklungsumgebung',3,40000,20 ,TO_DATE('05.10.06','DD.MM.YY'));
END;
```

It will not work But,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLERISIKO IS
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'drop table risiko';
    execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE Risiko
    (
        RNr       INTEGER,
        Projekt       INTEGER,
        Text       VARCHAR(25),
        Gruppe       INTEGER,
        Auswirkung    INTEGER,
        WKeit       INTEGER,
        Pruefdatum    DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY    (RNr),
        CONSTRAINT FKRisiko1 FOREIGN KEY (Projekt)
        REFERENCES Projekt(ProNr),
        CONSTRAINT FKRisiko2 FOREIGN KEY (Gruppe)
        REFERENCES Risikogruppe (RGNr),
        CONSTRAINT PosAuswirkung CHECK(Auswirkung >=0),
        CONSTRAINT WKeitProzent CHECK(WKeit>=0 AND WKeit<=100)
    )';
    execute immediate '
        INSERT INTO Risiko VALUES(1,1,||'''||'Anforderungenunklar'||'''||,1,50000,30 ,TO_DATE(||'''||'25.01.06'||'''||,||'''||'DD.MM.YY'||'''||));
        INSERT INTO Risiko VALUES(2,1,||'''||'Abnahmeprozess offen'||'''||,2,30000,70 ,TO_DATE(||'''||'26.02.06'||'''||,||'''||'DD.MM.YY'||'''||));
        INSERT INTO Risiko VALUES(3,2,||'''||'Ansprechpartner wechseln'||'''||,1,20000,80 ,TO_DATE(||'''||'06.05.06'||'''||,||'''||'DD.MM.YY'||'''||));
        INSERT INTO Risiko  VALUES(4,2,||'''||'neue Entwicklungsumgebung'||'''||,3,40000,20 ,TO_DATE(||'''||'05.10.06'||'''||,||'''||'DD.MM.YY'||'''||))';
    commit;
END;
```

It will run successfully.

Comment: Yeah this was one is it, i just have to mask it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `execute immediate` and probably `commit` the changes at the end.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLERISIKO IS


BEGIN
   execute immediate 'drop table risiko';
   execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE Risiko
      (
      RNr       INTEGER,
      Projekt       INTEGER,
      Text       VARCHAR(25),
      Gruppe       INTEGER,
      Auswirkung    INTEGER,
      WKeit       INTEGER,
      Pruefdatum    DATE,
      PRIMARY KEY    (RNr),
      CONSTRAINT FKRisiko1 FOREIGN KEY (Projekt)
      REFERENCES Projekt(ProNr),
      CONSTRAINT FKRisiko2 FOREIGN KEY (Gruppe)
      REFERENCES Risikogruppe (RGNr),
      CONSTRAINT PosAuswirkung CHECK(Auswirkung >=0),
      CONSTRAINT WKeitProzent CHECK(WKeit>=0 AND WKeit<=100)
      )';

   execute immediate 'INSERT INTO Risiko 
   VALUES(1,1,''Anforderungenunklar'',1,50000,30
   ,TO_DATE(''25.01.06'',''DD.MM.YY''))';
   execute immediate 'INSERT INTO Risiko 
   VALUES(2,1,''Abnahmeprozess offen'',2,30000,70
   ,TO_DATE(''26.02.06'',''DD.MM.YY''))';
   execute immediate 'INSERT INTO Risiko
   VALUES(3,2,''Ansprechpartner wechseln'',1,20000,80
   ,TO_DATE(''06.05.06'',''DD.MM.YY''))';
   execute immediate 'INSERT INTO Risiko
   VALUES(4,2,''neue Entwicklungsumgebung'',3,40000,20
   ,TO_DATE(''05.10.06'',''DD.MM.YY''))';
   commit;
END;
```

Comment: now its complaining on the insert statement, "[Error] ORA-00942 (24: 16): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

Comment: @AdrianObermühlner try now

Comment: You need to escape the single quotes in the `insert` statements by doubling them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right. I did it too fast and not very accurate. I'll fix it now

Answer (score 0):

Like this it works, just did the secon part like the first. Thanks for the help guys.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLERISIKO IS

BEGIN
   execute immediate 'drop table risiko';
   execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE Risiko
      (
      RNr       INTEGER,
      Projekt       INTEGER,
      Text       VARCHAR(25),
      Gruppe       INTEGER,
      Auswirkung    INTEGER,
      WKeit       INTEGER,
      Pruefdatum    DATE,
      PRIMARY KEY    (RNr),
      CONSTRAINT FKRisiko1 FOREIGN KEY (Projekt)
      REFERENCES Projekt(ProNr),
      CONSTRAINT FKRisiko2 FOREIGN KEY (Gruppe)
      REFERENCES Risikogruppe (RGNr),
      CONSTRAINT PosAuswirkung CHECK(Auswirkung >=0),
      CONSTRAINT WKeitProzent CHECK(WKeit>=0 AND WKeit<=100)
      )';
      commit;
   execute immediate '
   INSERT INTO Risiko 
   VALUES(1,1,||'''||'Anforderungenunklar'||'''||,1,50000,30
   ,TO_DATE(||'''||'25.01.06'||'''||,||'''||'DD.MM.YY'||'''||));
   INSERT INTO Risiko 
   VALUES(2,1,||'''||'Abnahmeprozess offen'||'''||,2,30000,70
   ,TO_DATE(||'''||'26.02.06'||'''||,||'''||'DD.MM.YY'||'''||));
   INSERT INTO Risiko
   VALUES(3,2,||'''||'Ansprechpartner wechseln'||'''||,1,20000,80
   ,TO_DATE(||'''||'06.05.06'||'''||,||'''||'DD.MM.YY'||'''||));
   INSERT INTO Risiko
   VALUES(4,2,||'''||'neue Entwicklungsumgebung'||'''||,3,40000,20
   ,TO_DATE(||'''||'05.10.06'||'''||,||'''||'DD.MM.YY'||'''||))';
   commit;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLERISIKO ( in_table_name     user_tables.table_name%TYPE) IS
  l_table_exists PLS_INTEGER;
  l_table_name user_tables.table_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
  l_table_name := 'RISIKO';

  SELECT COUNT ( *)
  INTO l_table_exists
  FROM user_tables
  WHERE table_name = l_table_name;

  IF l_table_exists = 1 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || l_table_name;
  END IF;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'CREATE TABLE ' || l_table_name || '
      (
      RNr       INTEGER,
      Projekt       INTEGER,
      Text       VARCHAR(25),
      Gruppe       INTEGER,
      Auswirkung    INTEGER,
      WKeit       INTEGER,
      Pruefdatum    DATE,
      PRIMARY KEY   (RNr),
      CONSTRAINT FK' || l_table_name || '1 FOREIGN KEY (Projekt)
      REFERENCES Projekt(ProNr),
      CONSTRAINT FK' || l_table_name || '2 FOREIGN KEY (Gruppe)
      REFERENCES ' || l_table_name || 'gruppe (RGNr),
      CONSTRAINT PosAuswirkung CHECK(Auswirkung >=0),
      CONSTRAINT WKeitProzent CHECK(WKeit>=0 AND WKeit<=100)
      )';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || l_table_name || ' VALUES (1, 1, ''Anforderungenunklar'', 1, 50000, 30, TO_DATE ( ''25.01.06'', ''DD.MM.YY2''))';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || l_table_name || ' VALUES (2, 1, ''Abnahmeprozess offen'', 2, 30000, 70, TO_DATE ( ''26.02.06'', ''DD.MM.YY''))';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || l_table_name || ' VALUES (3, 2, ''Ansprechpartner wechseln'', 1, 20000, 80, TO_DATE ( ''06.05.06'', ''DD.MM.YY''))';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || l_table_name || ' VALUES (4, 2, ''neue Entwicklungsumgebung'', 3, 40000, 20, TO_DATE ( ''05.10.06'', ''DD.MM.YY''))';

  COMMIT;
END;

BEGIN
  TABLERISIKO ( 'RISKO');
END;

SELECT * FROM risko;
```